# Why is my Ice Candidate request firing 6 times instead of 1?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm writing my first peer to peer connection application using WebRTC, and my code to request an ice candidate from the peer, which I send over a socket.io connection, is triggering 6 times rather than once.

This is really confusing because if I had mistakenly designed a big request loop, I would expect infinite recursions, not just 6 (8 `onicecandidate` events). So can anyone tell me why the follow code produced the 6 recursions?

Here's the message handler, it simply sends a socket.io message controlled by the syntax: `Muveoo.Messenger.input('ice candidate request', data);`

```
'ice candidate request' : function(data) {
    console.log('Debug 10: Requesting Ice Candidate');
    socket.emit('ice candidate request', data);
},
```

And here's the code that handles the Ice Candidate Request, dont be confused by the `if` logic at the very top, the UID is just a unique ID assigned to each client to decide who should make the offer initially.

```
if (Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name].UID < Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name].peerUID) {
    Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name].offerConnection(function() {
        console.log('[Debug A]: Offering Connection');
        Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name].pc.onicecandidate = function(evt) {
            console.log('[Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.');
            if (evt.candidate) {
                console.log('[Debug A]: Sending Ice Candidate Request.');
                Muveoo.Messenger.input('ice candidate request', {
                    target : id,
                    candidate : evt.candidate,
                    channel : name
                });
            }
        };
        Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name].pc.ondatachannel = function(evt) {
            console.log('got data channel');
            Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name] = evt.channel;
            Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name].channel.onmessage = function(evt1) {
                handleMessage(evt1.data);

            };
            Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name].channel.message = function(msg) {
                Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name].channel.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
            };
        };
        socket.on('session description', function(data) {
            console.log('Debug 12: Session Description Received');
            Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[data.target].dataChannels[data.channel].desc = new Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[data.target].dataChannels[data.channel].sessionDescription(msg.desc);
            Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[data.target].dataChannels[data.channel].pc.setRemoteDescription(Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[data.target].dataChannels[data.name].desc);
            if (Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[data.target].dataChannels[data.channel].UID > Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[data.target].dataChannels[data.channel].peerUID) {
                /*They sent the sessionDescription first, so need an answer*/
                Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[data.target].dataChannels[data.channel].pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
                    /*The answer is this side's local description*/
                    Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[data.target].dataChannels[data.channel].pc.setLocalDescription(answer);
                    var data = {
                        target : data.target,
                        description : answer,
                        channel : data.channel
                    };
                    socket.emit('session description', data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And here's the resulting logs to show what's going on:

```
[Debug A]: Offering Connection
rtc.js:94 [Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.
rtc.js:101 [Debug A]: Sending Ice Candidate Request.
messenger.js:91 Debug 10: Requesting Ice Candidate
rtc.js:94 [Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.
rtc.js:101 [Debug A]: Sending Ice Candidate Request.
messenger.js:91 Debug 10: Requesting Ice Candidate
rtc.js:94 [Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.
rtc.js:101 [Debug A]: Sending Ice Candidate Request.
messenger.js:91 Debug 10: Requesting Ice Candidate
rtc.js:94 [Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.
rtc.js:101 [Debug A]: Sending Ice Candidate Request.
messenger.js:91 Debug 10: Requesting Ice Candidate
rtc.js:94 [Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.
rtc.js:101 [Debug A]: Sending Ice Candidate Request.
messenger.js:91 Debug 10: Requesting Ice Candidate
rtc.js:94 [Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.
rtc.js:94 [Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.
rtc.js:101 [Debug A]: Sending Ice Candidate Request.
messenger.js:91 Debug 10: Requesting Ice Candidate
rtc.js:94 [Debug A]: onicecandidate Event Triggered.
```

**Why is my Ice Candidate request firing 6 times instead of 1?**

Comment: Hopefully this isnt too confusing but my namespace design  is meant to allow multiple connections between multiple candidates while offering exposure across various modules, `Muveoo.RTC.connectedPeers[id].dataChannels[name]` - the id just references a unique ID assigned to each client connected in the current session, and there are `video` and `audio` data channel names. I know this is bad for variable privacy but I'm the only developer of the application, so variable privacy isn't my focus at the moment. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not *requests*. You're responsible for sending however many ICE candidates WebRTC generates to the other peer through your choice of signaling.

This design is called *Trickle ICE*, and speeds up negotiation by not having to wait for all candidates to be found upfront and implanted into the offer/answer, which can take seconds, so please send these messages ASAP, as that's the whole point (you should already have sent the offer/answer already by the time these fire locally, i.e. after `setLocalDescription`'s success callback).

Each candidate is an IP + port that your local client can be reached at.

If you're sending video only (no audio) on a local LAN with no internet (or you're not specifying any STUN or TURN server), then you'll see two *host* candidates only, one for each direction. E.g.

```
candidate:0 1 UDP 2133252543 192.168.1.5 58078 typ host
candidate:0 2 UDP 2133252542 192.168.1.5 51446 typ host
```

If you add a STUN server, then you'll additionally see *server reflexive* candidates, i.e. how you're reachable from outside your firewall.

```
candidate:1 1 UDP 1686032863 69.102.28.57 60453 typ srflx
candidate:1 2 UDP 1686032862 69.102.28.57 62432 typ srflx
```

Lastly, if you add a TURN server, then you'll also see *relay* candidates, which are to a TURN server which will relay your data as a last resort (if no direct connection between the peers can be found):

```
candidate:2 1 UDP 1153102742 12.202.18.33 71321 typ relay
candidate:2 2 UDP 1153102741 12.202.18.33 71432 typ relay
```

Add audio to this, and the number of candidates double.

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0svkyLk/) to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

I just set a limit to it. I think you're supposed to need only one ICE candidate to send to the other peer

```
var limit = 0;    
this.pc.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
  if (limit == 0) {
     log("candidate");
     limit = 1;
  } else {
     return;
  }
});
```

Comment: You're not supposed to do that. ICE is taking a "try everything" approach and if you limit the other side's candidates it will try, it is more likely to fail.

Comment: But it didn't fail at least it worked for me. I did not limit the other side's candidate I just prevented it from firing and sending it more than once upon offer